# Docker: MariaDB becomes unavailable with time

Tags: windows, docker, mariadb

I pulled the mariadb image and launched it:

`docker run --name mariadb -p 3306: 3306 -d -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD = root -d mariadb / server: 10.3`

Everything works - I can connect both through `docker exec`, and with `Java` code. But after some time working with the database, the `Java` code and `IntelijIDEA` refuse to connect to the database. Although through the docer exec everything works as usual. `Windows 10` system. Maybe the Windows do something?

Comment: did you try using the shell in the docker-exec to connect to it? and do sample query?

Comment: also try telnet localhost:3306 from cmd/powershell

Comment: @FarhadFarahi Yes of course. Everything is working.

Comment: @FarhadFarahi `Connection to localhost: 3306 ... Could not open connection to this host, on port 23: Connection failed` when I tried `telnet localhost:3306`

Comment: @FarhadFarahi I restarted docker: `java` and `intellij idea` connected successfully, but command `telnet localhost:3306` get error.

Comment: your telnet command is wrong, should be `telnet localhost 3306`

Comment: @FarhadFarahi okay. I get this:`p
 5.5.5-10.3.13-MariaDB-1:10.3.13+maria~bionic
                                             my8HD[}&■┐БAVi0Q)v9X.z>mysql_native_password`

Comment: this means right now docker and mariadb are working fine, you just connected form host to the container, if right now you have trouble with intellij/java you need to check your configuration